# how to create a google sign in popup on the Python Flask website

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I would like to create a google sign-in popup similar to https://www.reddit.com/. on the right side of this page, you can see "Sign in to Reddit with Google", I want this similar on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) for Sign-in with Google
2. If you want to give users the ability to sign-in with other providers e.g. Apple, Twitter, etc, then you should checkout Firebase from Google. The documentation for their sign-in can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui)